# Rider/Resharper - Require names on optional parameters

Tags: c#, resharper, rider

In Rider/Resharper is there a way to enforce parameter names on only optional parameters?

For example if you had the method:

```cs
public void MyMethod(string message, int code = 0, string description = null) {}
```

When I go to invoke this method, is it possible to enforce that I must always supply the names for the optional parameters (or at least have it show as a hint/warning)? So that it would make me invoke the method like this

```cs
MyMethod("Hello World", code: 123, description: "My description");
```

Comment: Based [on this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Argument_Style.html) you can enforce to have argument names everywhere. I don't think that it will omit the name if does not have default value.

Comment: @PeterCsala I've tried this before, and sadly, as you said, it will enforce the parameter name on every parameter, not just optional ones.